# How to generate TSval for TCP Timestamp option, in python?

Tags: python, networking, tcp, scapy

I am trying to implement a receiving side of the TCP protocol via `scapy`.

I have node `A` who sends some random json file over TCP to node `B`, and I am trying to write the receiving side of TCP using `scapy` for node B. I am sniffing packets in `scapy` and trying to ACK incoming packets from node `B`.

I have figured out how to set correct ACK and SEQ numbers for the ACK packets I construct, but I'm struggling with creating correct Timestamp TCP options. I have read in RFC-1323 that Timestamp contains `TSval` and `TSecr`. I set `TSecr` by copying the `TSval` from the incoming packet, but from what I understand, I need to set `TSval` to be the current time of the system. I'm not sure how to get the time correctly. I tried doing the following in python

```
import time
TSval = int(time.time())
```

But it doesn't give me the correct value because the value of `TSecr` is something like 3130283869 whereas the above snippet gives me something like 1539307653 (almost 2x smaller). It's not clear to me what kind of time is represented by `Tsecr` and `TSval`. Is it epoch time? Is it something else?

Comment: Are you sure that a simple TCP serversocket / socket implementation is not enough ? Scapy is more focused on low-level networking.

Comment: While it is no doubt that the specific scenario I described could use existing TCP socket implementation, in reality I have actually simplified my real scenario in order to ask a question on StackOverflow. So yes, I know that Scapy is focused on low level networking and it is exactly why I am using it and simple TCP serversocket/socket implementation is not enough for me.

Comment: My bad I didn’t get the question. What you are asking seems very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/27812542/5459467

Comment: I saw it but it didn't answer my question because it does not say how to calculate the values :( The answer provided only explains what TSval and TSecr mean and links to their official definition but it's still not helpful for actually creating those values via python.